# Reindex fails with array mapped to geo_point

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to reindex after changing the mapping of one field from type text to type `geo_point`.

The existing data in the source index looks like:

```
  "location" : {
    "lat_long" : [
      "49.266498",
      "-122.998938"
    ],
```

how ever on the `_reindex` api call I get the following failures:

```
"cause": {
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse field [location.lat_long] of type [geo_point]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "parse_exception",
      "reason": "unsupported symbol [.] in geohash [49.228065]",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "unsupported symbol [.] in geohash [49.228065]"
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that in your `source_index` i.e. `latitude.lat_long` field doesn't conform to any of the valid four different representations supported by [`geo_point`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html) dataype.

As a result conversion fails when you try to reindex.

The only applicable *string* representation would be of the below format `"lat, lon"`, however the one you have is `[ "lat", "lon" ]` which is nothing but array of strings.

If the representation is in below format, the reindex would execute successfully.

```
"location" : {
    "lat_long" : "49.266498, -122.998938"
    ]
 }
```

As a solution, what you can do is execute the below steps:

### Step 1: Create [Ingest Pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/pipeline.html)

Execute the below query in order to create a pipeline that would convert the `input format` of `latitude.lat_long` to the required format as I've mentioned above

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my-pipeline-geo
{
  "description" : "geo-point pipeline",
  "processors" : [
    {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "ctx.temp = \"\"; for (def item : ctx.location.lat_long) { if(ctx.temp==\"\") { ctx.temp += item } else { ctx.temp = ctx.temp + ', ' + item} }"
        }
      },
      {
        "remove": {
          "field": "location"
        }
      },
      {
        "set": {
          "field": "location.lat_long",
          "value": "{{temp}}"
        }
      },
      {
        "remove": {
          "field": "temp"
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

### Step 2: Execute the below reindex query

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "source_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dest_index",
    "pipeline": "my-pipeline-geo"
  }
}
```

Notice how I've used the pipeline created in **Step 1**, during the reindexing step. 
The output would be in the format as I've mentioned above. Do take sometime out to read about the inbuilt [Ingestion API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) there is in elasticsearch.

Test, verify and let me know how it goes.

Comment: hey @WindDude, did the above help. Are you looking for something else?